# How to know when the ViewPort3D finishes render?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.7.2, viewport3d

After moving a perspective camera of the ViewPort3D, the rendering of the 3D visuals takes some seconds to fully render.

There's no "Rendered" event or anything like that.

Is there any way to detect when the render finishes?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot do that because there's no property in ViewPort3D to serve what you want.

The nearest one is using the inherited property of ViewPort3D, the `IsInitialized` property. This property will tell you whether a FrameworkElement such as ViewPort3D is completing `EndInit` (finishing init) or not.

Since you aren't mentioning about which platform do you use, I assume you are using .NET Framework 4.7 and later instead of .NET Core.

Here's the official documentation on `IsInitialized` property:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.isinitialized?view=netframework-4.7

Comment: Yes, I'm on .NET Framework, I added that tag.